# Cómo puedo leer por teclado un número indefinido de floats en la misma línea en java

Tags: java, float, entrada

Buenas. Necesito leer por teclado un número de floats que **no conozco**, ya que el usuario podrá meter los que él quiera. Además lo hará en la **misma lína**, separando los números con espacios. Una entrada posible sería: "1 1,2 3 4,5 1,2". El problema es que **no conozco cuántos números introducirá el usuario**, si no utilizaría los métodos *.nextFloat()* y *.close()* pero no es el caso. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y leerlos como un gran string y despues parsearlos?